# How to translate "The stolen letter of Arithmetic"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to give a memorable title to a short text that I am writing and I thought of the above one in reference to the short novel by E. A. Poe, *The Purloined Letter*.

A few attempts with automatic translation tools gave me mediocre results and my Latin is unfortunately very rusty. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this translation.

Nb.: *the capitalized word "Arithmetic" refers to the field of mathematics studying numbers and is thus intended as a noun, not an adjective.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a relatively simple answer, only requiring three (or four) words, the nouns *epistola* and *arithmētica*, and the perfect passive participle of the verb *surripiō*, *surreptus*. All combined together, you get the following phrase:

> *Epistola surrepta Arithmēticae*

If you want to be fancy, *arithmētica* is a Greek loanword and can thus be declined using its Greek declension, utilizing the genitive *-ēs* ending instead of the standard *-ae*.

> *Epistola surrepta Arithmēticēs*

In addition, if the word *the* is emphatic in your English title, you might want to consider using the weak demonstrative adjective, like so:

> *Ea epistola surrepta Arithmēticae (-ēs)*

As is with Latin, you can rearrange the word order to your personal preference; I am simply following your original order for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @SamuelVidal No problem! I am curious, however; which one of these did you ultimately end up selecting?

Comment: I'm not too sure yet. I like that you gave several options giving me elements to explain them. Arithmēticae is good since latin is fancy enough. The emphatic Ea matches the title of the novel, so I might keep it, but I like the shortness of the first translation so I think I will chose this one.